# MapStruct integration with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, mapstruct

anyone know if there is (or is plan to be) some kind of extension for VSCode to use MapStruct better and smarter as in IDEA or Eclipse?
I mean some tool as IDEA or Eclipse Plugin to easily manage the mappers.

In the official page https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/ there's nothing about VSCode.

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is roadmap question about the plans of the MapStruct team. In my opinion such questions don't belong to StackOverflow

Answer (score -2):

your example doesn't even build from CLI:

./gradlew build                                ✔  11:12:33 

Welcome to Gradle 5.6.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Incremental Groovy compilation
- Groovy compile avoidance
- Test fixtures for Java projects
- Manage plugin versions via settings script

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 6 busy and 1 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/fbricon/Dev/souk/mapstruct-gradle-demo/build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'halo'.

> Could not get resource 'http://saos-publish-test.chj.cloud/gradle/version.gradle'.
> Could not GET 'http://saos-publish-test.chj.cloud/gradle/version.gradle'.
> > saos-publish-test.chj.cloud: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

Comment: why does an answer about gradle helps a question about mapstruct

Comment: I think there is some mistake about the answer. I'm asking for Mapstruct plugin for VSCode, not how to build with gradle....! Pls check/review your answer.